# Is it a bad idea to use CpuLimit with Monero software?

Tags: wallet, cpu

CpuLimit is a Linux program that sends `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` signals to a program to throttle it's CPU usage. I have a Monero service that keeps wallets in sync by opening them, syncing them, and closing them on loop - but it's very CPU intensive on my server.

My question is if I run CpuLimit, will the Monero software still behave as expected, or will some complexities in the threading/communication with daemon/etc/etc cause unintended side-effects?

edit: For reference, this is the command I'm running:

```
cpulimit -l 50 -- ~/monero-wallet-rpc --wallet-file ./wallets/wallet353 --password ${PW} --rpc-bind-port ${PORT}  --disable-rpc-login
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine, unless the programs stay stopped for a long time, in which cases timeouts may occur. If you're local, timeouts with a single client is more than 3 minutes IIRC, so it should be just fine. I've done this a few times before with a loop and kill `pidof monerod` and there was no problem.